# read and delete blob content together in single action in Azure Logic App

Tags: blob, azure-logic-apps

Read and delete in different actions in logic app is possible but
How can we read and delete blob content together in single action in azure logic app ?

Comment: It is not possible using out of the box connector. you could create a function app that would read and delete then call it from your logic app. not sure if that would worse it tho.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, Logic Apps doesn't support such actions. You always need to add different actions for reading and deletion steps. However, you can try checking [custom connector in Azure Logic Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/custom-connectors/create-logic-apps-connector).